# Instance error in OOP design: Instance of Card has No points member

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm reading this book called Master Object Oriented programming Python by Steven Lott.

I came across this code:

```
class Card:
    def  __init__( self, rank, suit ):
        self.suit= suit
        self.rank= rank
        self.hard, self.soft = self._points()
class NumberCard( Card ):
    def _points( self ):
        return int(self.rank), int(self.rank)
class AceCard( Card ):
    def _points( self ):
        return 1, 11
class FaceCard( Card ):
    def _points( self ):
        return 10, 10
```

I'm not able to understand how can `self._points()` in Card be legal expression.

I run the code in compiler too it stats the following error
Instance of Card has No points member

[image: Error Image]
Full Code I have kept it as gist  [here](https://gist.github.com/vidit0210/289036899e0ddc7885bc2849b5d967e1)

Comment: Show a reproducible example of how you run your code. The error you list is unrelated to what you show here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist added error Image

Comment: Please don't ever post text as screenshots. You did so well with the code formatting until now, keep it up

Comment: The code you posted here just creates classes but never runs them. Show code here that actually reproduce your error. Something I can copy into my editor and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error: it is just a pylint issue, if you do not do something like `c = Card(1, 2)`, it will be ok.

The code in fact is correct.

It intends you will call it like `n = NumberCard(1, 2)`, then `__init__` will be used by its subclass, and subclass has the function `_points`.

In fact, for other language, usually we need to define a `_points` function in parent class. Then, subclass could override the function in parent class. But `python` is not so strict, so you could do without define `_points` function in parent class, but then you will just able to new a object for its subclass not parent class.

To sum all, what you need to google is `function override` of OOP.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__()` function of the base class, `Card`, tries to access the member function `_points()`, when it has none. That its subclasses all have such a member function doesn't help the base class from getting this member function. You simply can't instantiate `Card` directly because it really is an abstract class.

You should use the `abc` module to declare `Card` as an abstract class, and `Card._points` as an abstract method, and instantiate child classes instead:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Card(ABC):
    def  __init__( self, rank, suit ):
        self.suit= suit
        self.rank= rank
        self.hard, self.soft = self._points()
    @abstractmethod
    def _points(self):
        return None, None
class NumberCard( Card ):
    def _points( self ):
        return int(self.rank), int(self.rank)
class AceCard( Card ):
    def _points( self ):
        return 1, 11
class FaceCard( Card ):
    def _points( self ):
        return 10, 10

a=AceCard(1,2)
print(a.hard, a.soft)
```